# Table showing titles

Tags: tables

I would like to make a table of titles which will look like this

```
A   First Title
B   Second Title

and so on
```

I am unsure whether to make a new environment or a new command for this.

Currently I am doing

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{appendix}

\title{Proposal}
\author{Rama}
\date{October 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\appendix
\appendixpage
\addappheadtotoc

\noindent\textbf{A \quad First Title}

\smallskip\noindent\textbf{B \quad Second Title}

\newpage
\section{First Title}
  
\newpage
\section{Second Title}

\end{document}
```

One can use tables (e.g. list, enumeration, tabular) but the text is smaller and there is some indentation.

`etoc` is a massive thing.  I only want a small simple list a few Appendix Titles which will not be enormous.

Comment: Again, no minimal example and no context. Your `\smallskip` puts space after the second title. If these are titles of things in your document, such as appendices, you don't want to enter them manually at all. But I already mentioned `etoc`. (There are other similar options - that's just the one I've used.)

Comment: You might also look at minitoc.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
\begin{tabular}{ ll } % use 'l' ("left aligned") col. type
  A & First Title \\
  B & Second Title
\end{tabular}
```

If all contents need to be rendered in **bold**, I suggest you *not* use lots of `\textbf` directives. Instead, just load the `array` package in the preamble and replace `\begin{tabular}{ ll }` with `\begin{tabular}{ >{\bfseries}l >{\bfseries}l }`. Can you guess what `>{\bfseries}` does?

---

The result of making these code snippets compilable:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{ ll } 
  A & First Title \\
  B & Second Title
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{ >{\bfseries}l >{\bfseries}l } 
  A & First Title \\
  B & Second Title
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses enumerate (just for fun).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{enumitem}% not really needed, but useful}

\title{Proposal}
\author{Rama}
\date{October 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\appendix
\appendixpage
\addappheadtotoc

\textbf{\begin{enumerate}[label=\Alph*]
  \item First Title
  \item Second Title
\end{enumerate}}

\newpage
\section{First Title}
  
\newpage
\section{Second Title}

\end{document}
```